# Write database queries in Magento custom module

Tags: mysql, magento, module

I created a custom module in my Magento. This is working good. My module's name is `mymodule`. 
**Mymodule.php**

```
class Myshop_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        return "Hello User";
    }
}
```

The path of the `Mymodule.php` file is `C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\local\Myshop\Mymodule\Block`.

Now I want to display some data from database. For example I would like to display the admin's email id. How can I display this??

I tried like this.

```
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
//database write adapter
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$result = $read->fetchAll("select email from admin_user where user_id= 1");
var_dump($result);
```

I write these lines in `Mymodule.php` inside `myfunction`. But nothing displayed(display only "Hello User").

So my question is how to display or write database queries in `magento custom module`.

Please someone help me..Any help is really appreciable..

Answer (score 1):

We generally avoid using adapters when magento by default provides models for the basic tables. In your case, you can fetch the admin details using following :

```
<?php
    $userDetails = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load(1);
    //where 1 is your admin user id
    echo $userDetails->getEmail();
?>
```

Hence, your function can be modified as :

```
<?php 
class Myshop_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function myfunction()
    {
        $userDetails = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load(1);
        return $userDetails->getEmail();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from database in magento as

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("mumodule/mymodule")->getCollection();
foreach($collection as $data){
    ..Your Code ..
}
```